# Storing php session data in a cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know that the default PHP session storage mechanism is a file, usually in tmp. And the session_id is carried in a cookie.

I want to also store my small amount of session data in the cookie too. (Like Rails does by default.)

**Question:** Is there a php library to handle this for me or do I need to roll my own using [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) etc?

Added: Is *just* the [CodeIgniter session class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) available?

Comment: Don't mess with the PHP session cookie. If you want to store data in a cookie, then use ANOTHER cookie.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to ask yourself is **why** you are doing this. Provided that you provide your session ID, you can access any information present in the session itself. If you prefer to do it any other way, you will have to roll your own session system.

Here are a couple of points against what you have in mind:

- Cookies have a maximum size (4kb). It is actually pretty common for CI cookies to overflow.
- The information in the file server-side is guaranteed tamper-proof (or as tamper-proof as your server). The information in the cookie is not
- If it is the "OMG DISK READ" thing that is scaring you - you can always bind `redis` as your session manager. It is actually trivial to do.
- Finally, you will have a significant PITA the moment your code gets ported elsewhere

Assuming you still want to do it (are you really sure?), the answer is just to set another cookie. PHP session handlers are best not to mess around with due to the significant risk of throwing 500s all over the place if a change goes wrong. A second cookie is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...but if it is such a bad idea, why is it now the default for Rails? Encryption can handle the security issue if need be. ps I'm fine with using a second cookie, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);



$this->input->set_cookie($newdata);
```

Comment: OP's not asking how to use CodeIgniter

Comment: @DamienPirsy: That's when you downvote and/or report as not an answer. + low quality on this specific specimen.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld  I prefer to leave a comment before casting a downvote (which I didn't, here). By the way, this IS an answer and IS NOT low quality (well, borderline maybe) - according to the guidelines as I read them, those flags could be rejected. I prefer to warn the poster that he might have misunderstood the question - which can very well be the case here